# apcluster in R: Memory limitation

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to run clustering exercise in R. The algorithm that I used is `apcluster()`. The script that I used is:

```
s1        <- negDistMat(df, r=2, method="euclidean")
apcluster <- apcluster(s1)
```

My data set is having around 0.1 million rows. When I ran the script, I got the following error:

> `Error in simpleDist(x[, sapply(x, is.numeric)], sel, method = method,  :
>   negative length vectors are not allowed`

When I searched online, I found out that negative length vector error occurs due to the memory limit of my RAM. My question is if there is any workaround to run `apcluster()` on my dataset with 0.1 million rows with the available RAM, or am I missing something that I will need to take care while running `apcluster` in R?

I have a machine with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: On data sets of this size, you don't want to use algorithms that need O(n²) memory and supposedly even O(n³) time. Instead, try the `dbscan` package, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The standard version of affinity propagation implemented in the `apcluster()` method will never ever run successfully on data of that size. On the one hand, the similarity matrix (s1 in your code sample) will have 100K x 100K = 10G entries. On the other hand, computation times will be excessive. I suggest you use `apclusterL()` instead.